# qué debe de ir dentro de los corchetes de la funcion "constructor" en ionic?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Sé que en el `constructor` cargo algunas dependencias como plugins o se cargan providers que usaré en la clase. pero no sé que debe de ir dentro de los corchetes? en algunos casos esta vacio, pero en otros se definen variables. cúal es la mejor práctica y cuando se pone conentido dentro de estos corchetes, qué se debe de incluir?

```
constructor(
 public navCtrl: NavController // for example
){
 ????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El constructor es una función que se llama inmediatamente cuando se crea la instancia de una clase, normalmente se inicializan variables y se definen valores, si por el contrario lo que usted necesita es consumir un servicio o ejecutar procesos complejos de lógica, se recomiendan utilizan los estados de vida del aplicativo por ejemplo la función ionViewDidLoad.

Comment: gracias, pero qué debe de ir en los corchetes,que difernecia habria en poner una variable dentro de los corchetes del constructor  o en ioniViewDidLoad por ejemplo